# java.lang.NullPointerException with C# target

Tags: c#, antlr

I tried to update a Antlr3 grammar file we use for parsing our own DSL to the new Antlr4 format.

After eliminating all syntax errors whith AntlrWorks2 I integrated this grammar in a Visual Studio 2013 test project which includes the Antlr 4.3.0 C# targe runtime library.
But I only get following callstack while compiling this grammar:

Unknown build error:

```
Executing command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe" -cp D:\Projects\Antlr4Test\packages\Antlr4.4.3.0\build\..\tools\antlr4-csharp-4.3-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.CSharpTool -o obj\Debug\ -listener -visitor -Dlanguage=CSharp_v4_5 -package Antlr4Test D:\Projects\Antlr4Test\Antlr4Test\UpsSharp.g4 (TaskId:10)
1>D:\Projects\Antlr4Test\packages\Antlr4.4.3.0\build\Antlr4.targets(132,5): error AC1000: Unknown build error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
1>D:\Projects\Antlr4Test\packages\Antlr4.4.3.0\build\Antlr4.targets(132,5): error AC1000: Unknown build error:     at org.antlr.v4.automata.ParserATNFactory.elemList(ParserATNFactory.java:490)
1>D:\Projects\Antlr4Test\packages\Antlr4.4.3.0\build\Antlr4.targets(132,5): error AC1000: Unknown build error:     at org.antlr.v4.automata.ParserATNFactory.alt(ParserATNFactory.java:477)
1>D:\Projects\Antlr4Test\packages\Antlr4.4.3.0\build\Antlr4.targets(132,5): error AC1000: Unknown build error:     at org.antlr.v4.parse.ATNBuilder.alternative(ATNBuilder.java:556)
1>D:\Projects\Antlr4Test\packages\Antlr4.4.3.0\build\Antlr4.targets(132,5): error AC1000: Unknown build error:     at org.antlr.v4.parse.ATNBuilder.ruleBlock(ATNBuilder.java:290)
1>D:\Projects\Antlr4Test\packages\Antlr4.4.3.0\build\Antlr4.targets(132,5): error AC1000: Unknown build error:     at org.antlr.v4.automata.ParserATNFactory._createATN(ParserATNFactory.java:186)
1>D:\Projects\Antlr4Test\packages\Antlr4.4.3.0\build\Antlr4.targets(132,5): error AC1000: Unknown build error:     at org.antlr.v4.automata.LexerATNFactory.createATN(LexerATNFactory.java:134)
1>D:\Projects\Antlr4Test\packages\Antlr4.4.3.0\build\Antlr4.targets(132,5): error AC1000: Unknown build error:     at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processNonCombinedGrammar(Tool.java:405)
1>D:\Projects\Antlr4Test\packages\Antlr4.4.3.0\build\Antlr4.targets(132,5): error AC1000: Unknown build error:     at org.antlr.v4.Tool.process(Tool.java:376)
1>D:\Projects\Antlr4Test\packages\Antlr4.4.3.0\build\Antlr4.targets(132,5): error AC1000: Unknown build error:     at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processGrammarsOnCommandLine(Tool.java:343)
1>D:\Projects\Antlr4Test\packages\Antlr4.4.3.0\build\Antlr4.targets(132,5): error AC1000: Unknown build error:     at org.antlr.v4.CSharpTool.main(CSharpTool.java:59)
1>Done executing task "Antlr4ClassGenerationTask" -- FAILED. (TaskId:10)
```

Trying to compile example grammars is working fine!
We don`t have much experience with Antlr and just want to update to Antlr4, so perhaps somebody has an idea what happens?

Thanks in advance!
Holger